# The correct separator to use in Excel get_Range in VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, cultureinfo

In a VSTO project for Excel written in C#, I need to get the Range object from a string list of cells.

Here is a simplified version of the problem:

```
string strRange = "A1:A2,A5";
Excel.Range r = sheet.get_Range(strRange);
```

However since the list separator can be different from the comma in different culture settings I'm actually using this:

```
listSep = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator;
string strRange = "A1:A2" + listSep + "A5";
Excel.Range r = sheet.get_Range(strRange);
```

My problem is when the user changes "Decimal Separator" in Excel Options > Advanced (the Application.DecimalSeparator) to match the ListSeparator, this won't work.

What is the correct way to call get_Range with a string specifying the Range?

EDIT: Slight modification to add information of my comment below.

Comment: The format should always be `Cell1:Cell2,Cell3` afaik - that's how the API works and should not be affected by `ListSeparator`. There is an alternative suggestion in this answer, however: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155182/excel-get-range-with-multiple-areas

Comment: When the the ListSeperator as per CultureInfo is ',' and the Application.DecimalSeparator is also ',' the separator to be used is ';'. But why? where has it been documented?

Comment: @dash: No, get_Range(<string>) is affected by Culture settings.

Answer (score 4):

Not the cleanest approach, but this workaround helped me:

```
private static string GetRangeSeparator(Excel.Worksheet sheet)
{
     Excel.Application app = sheet.Application;
     string sRng = app.Union(sheet.get_Range("A1"), sheet.get_Range("A3")).AddressLocal;
     sRng = sRng.Replace("$", string.Empty);
     string sSep = sRng.Substring(sRng.IndexOf("A3") - 1, 1);
     return sSep;
}
```

Hope it'll help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the `Application.Union` method to build your range.  Something like (untested):

```
Application.Union(sheet.get_Range("A1:A2"), sheet.get_Range("A5"));
```

Comment: Yes, this is an alternative/workaround. But as mentioned in my question the problem is to **find the correct separator** for a range definition. 
I can't use the Application.Union due to its bad performance in huge data volumes.