# Select collection of cells

Tags: c#, excel, interop, excel-interop

I need to select a collection of cells in a worksheet. I could find how to select a range, but not when the cells are "isolated".

For example "$D$4", $G$9" ...

My code:

```
var excelApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;

List<string> unlockedCells = new List<string>();
foreach (_Excel.Range cells in excelApp.ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
{
    if (!cells.Locked)
    {
        unlockedCells.Add(cells.Address);
    }
}

unlockedCells.ForEach(_c =>
{
    excelApp.Range[_c].Select();
});
```

The problem here is that every time a new range is selected, the previous selection is lost.

Another approach. It doesn't work, raises exception `Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application.get_Range(Object Cell1, Object Cell2)`

The range I get is the following: `"$D$8,$E$8,$D$9,$E$9,$D$10,$E$10,$D$11,$E$11,$D$12,$E$12"`

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
...
output.Append(String.Format("{0},", cells.Address));
string rangeDef = output.ToString().Left(output.Length - 1);
excelApp.Range[rangeDef].Select();
```

How could I achieve it?

Office Version 2016

Comment: Create a string of cell references in your loop and than select those cells using the string that you have created after your loop.

Comment: @ManishChristian I have tried already this solution and didn't work. I will modify the question to show what I also did.

Comment: See if [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6155286/1652222) answer might work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Whenever I try to add more range, I get COM exception. I cannot pass "D8,E9" as parameter to the `get_Range` or use it as index of `Range`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<string> cells = new List<string>();
cells.Add("$C$4");
cells.Add("$D$5");
cells.Add("$H$10");

for (int idx = 0; idx < cells.Count; idx++)
    cells[idx] = String.Format("'{0}'!{1}", (excelApp.ActiveSheet as _Excel.Worksheet).Name, cells[idx]);
string rangeDef = String.Format("={0}", String.Join(";", cells));

var sheet = (excelApp.ActiveSheet as _Excel.Worksheet).get_Range(rangeDef, Type.Missing).Select();
```

It seems I was missing the worksheet name.

Answer (score 0):

Although the `excelApp` itself does have a `Range` property, the workbook or worksheet is ambiguous.  Instead, try to reference the `Range` of a certain worksheet:

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
output.Append("C4,");
output.Append("D5,");
output.Append("E6,");
string rangeDef = output.ToString().Substring(0, output.Length - 1);

Worksheet worksheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet;
Range range = worksheet.Range[rangeDef];
range.Value = "test";
```

Worked for me for some minimal testing.

Comment: I tried this. Also not working, same error. I suspect this has is somehow related to my office version. 2016. Any idea?